# How do you flag a question for closure when the reason for closing is not in the menu?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/57395/), the user is asking about how/where to purchase a part. This is a specific violation of the network rules

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> If [your question is] not about…
>
> Resource location.
>   Where to buy a specific part, "Which headset is the best?", Where can I get a feed of flight-related data? etc.

However, when I attempted to flag this question, working through the menu does not arrive at the reason this question should be closed/deleted.

The first option in the menu, that I believe should be the correct reason, is: **Should be Closed**, which brings up the following sub-menu:

- duplicate of...
- off-topic because...
- unclear what you're asking
- too broad
- primarily opinion-based

Selecting **Off Topic** brings up the next menu:

- Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with aviation)
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Neither of these options is accurate.

There is no (apparent) method for flagging a question as "does not meet the rules listed in the Help Center".  What is the best way to flag this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "Blatantly off-topic" choice says the following when you have a higher rep:

> This question does not appear to be about aviation, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help).

The help centre is exactly where you found the details of subjects which are [on-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (and also which are off-topic).

So the answer is that was the right option to choose.

---

Edit: The option I see is rep-specific and I'm attempting to get an answer on when a user sees the "Blatantly off topic" message from the one I see.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess that's a *technically* correct answer, since you included (and I omitted) the part about "within the scope defined in the help center".  I still maintain that it is ambiguous, and that this ambiguity is not good for newcomers to the network.  If this person's question is closed for the reason of being "blatantly off topic - does not appear to be about aviation", simply having that phrase will not eliminate the confusion since his question was obviously VERY related to aviation. I guess I'll go investigate the procedure for recommending changes.

Comment: @Jimmy we can add custom close reasons, but nobody that Im aware of has ever suggested one. Perhaps you should start another meta with your suggestion and let the community vote on it.

Answer (score 2):

Flag it as "off-topic", then "blatantly off-topic". The phrase "blatantly off-topic" isn't actually accurate, but it's the least inaccurate of the available options, and it will result in the correct thing happening (namely, being added to the review queue to be closed).