# Request to add a 3rd option to the "Off Topic" options when flagging a question as OT

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I would like to propose that the "Off Topic" closure flag reasons be updated to include a 3rd option:

- "*Aviation related, but inappropriate topic as defined in the [off-topic section of the help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).*"

---

When initially selecting the Off Topic reason, there is a caveat that the question is off topic because it is not "within the scope defined in the help center".  This caveat does indeed mean that *aviation topics* can be "off topic" by virtue of being an expressly-prohibited topic, such as accident speculation. 
[image]

However, when proceeding to the final page, there are only two options available and neither one is accurate.

- **Blatantly off-topic** (this question has nothing to do with aviation)
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

I propose that a 3rd option be added, as described above. At the moment, newer members attempting to flag a question as being "off topic", but still aviation related, can become confused when navigating the menu tree. Selecting this option will help members, who are flagging a question, more accurately define the reason as an off-topic-but-still-aviation-related question.

Answer (score 4):

The final page of options is only for the flag. For users with >=3k rep, here are the off-topic close reasons they can choose here:

[image: Close Reasons]

The top reason is what gets shown on the question if it gets closed. I agree that "as defined in the help center" covers things that may not be blatantly off-topic. People voting to close can always use the "other" option to be more specific, and this gets added as a comment on the post.

By the way, the "belongs on another site" option right now only lets us choose our meta site, so it's common for people to use the comment and say something like "because it belongs on Travel.SE"

Comment: Thanks, @fooot.  Should I modify my question/request to be more specifically aimed at the person flagging the question?  When I attempted to submit my first "flag" the other day, I could not get through the menus at all.  As a person new to the process of flagging things as off topic, I eventually backed out and ended up not flagging the question because I was not sure what to do. The "actual" reason for the flag was nowhere to be found, when I finally arrived at that last page with only 2 options, neither of which were true.

Comment: When I asked "how" do I flag this (here: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3729) it was suggested that I make a feature request to add a 3rd option.  Perhaps the request justification should be for the person flagging, and not necessarily as a "benefit to the OP"?

Comment: @Jimmy I agree, other sites have additional flags that are more specific, and it seems like there should be other options besides "blatantly off topic"